# Project Euler problem 11 in Rust: largest product of consecutive elements in a grid

Tags: programming-challenge, rust

I wrote the following Rust code for [euler project problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11). It works and a small test is included, but I am not very happy about the code.

At first I wanted to chain together iterators for all the lines that need to be checked, but I could not make that work:

```
// FIXME: this doesn't work, so learn more Rust to DRY
// let all = horizontal
//     .chain(vertical)
//     .chain(top_to_bottom_right)
//     .chain(left_to_bottom_right)
//     .chain(top_to_bottom_left)
//     .chain(right_to_bottom_left);
// all.map(|line| largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n))
//     .max()
//     .unwrap()
```

So I ended up duplicating a lot of code. Six copies of this:

```
// let max_h = horizontal
//     .map(|line| {
//         largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n)
//     })
//     .max()
//     .unwrap();
```

Then I abstracted this pattern with a function, but look at those absurd trait bounds:

```
fn max_of_lines<Iter: Iterator>(grid: &[usize], n: usize, lines: Iter) -> usize
where
    <Iter as Iterator>::Item: Iterator,
    <<Iter as Iterator>::Item as Iterator>::Item: SliceIndex<[usize]>,
    <<<Iter as Iterator>::Item as Iterator>::Item as SliceIndex<[usize]>>::Output: Copy + Sized,
    Vec<usize>: FromIterator<
        <<<Iter as Iterator>::Item as Iterator>::Item as SliceIndex<[usize]>>::Output,
    >,
{
    lines
        .map(|line| {
            largest_adjacent_product_of_length(
                &line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<usize>>(),
                n,
            )
        })
        .max()
        .unwrap()
}
```

Is there a way of fixing this?

Full code (also on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f51fa671dce9263f5cf6f59fc555d478)):

```
#[test]
fn test_it() {
    let grid_str = "\
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
6 2 3 4 3
1 2 4 3 5";
    let grid = &read_grid(grid_str);
    assert_eq!(largest_product_in_grid(grid, 5, 1), 6);
    assert_eq!(largest_product_in_grid(grid, 5, 2), 5 * 5);
    assert_eq!(largest_product_in_grid(grid, 5, 3), 5 * 4 * 4);
}

pub fn largest_product_in_grid_str(grid: &str, width: usize, n: usize) -> usize {
    largest_product_in_grid(&read_grid(grid), width, n)
}

pub fn largest_product_in_grid(grid: &[usize], width: usize, n: usize) -> usize {
    use std::slice::SliceIndex;
    fn max_of_lines<Iter: Iterator>(grid: &[usize], n: usize, lines: Iter) -> usize
    where
        <Iter as Iterator>::Item: Iterator,
        <<Iter as Iterator>::Item as Iterator>::Item: SliceIndex<[usize]>,
        <<<Iter as Iterator>::Item as Iterator>::Item as SliceIndex<[usize]>>::Output: Copy + Sized,
        Vec<usize>: FromIterator<
            <<<Iter as Iterator>::Item as Iterator>::Item as SliceIndex<[usize]>>::Output,
        >,
    {
        lines
            .map(|line| {
                largest_adjacent_product_of_length(
                    &line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<usize>>(),
                    n,
                )
            })
            .max()
            .unwrap()
    }

    use std::cmp::min;
    // idea: create list of indices, map into list of elements, problem 8
    grid.chunks_exact(width);
    let height = grid.len() / width;
    // search horizontally; this is problem 8 for each row
    let horizontal = (0..height).map(|row| {
        let rw = row * width;
        rw..rw + width
    });
    // search vertically; should make this problem 8 too
    let vertical = (0..width).map(|col| (0..height).map(move |n| col + n * width));
    // search diagonally-top-left-bottom-right
    let diag = min(width, height);
    let top_to_bottom_right =
        (0..width).map(|col| (0..min(diag, width - col)).map(move |n| col + n * (width + 1)));
    let left_to_bottom_right =
        (0..height).map(|row| (0..min(diag, height - row)).map(move |n| width * (row + n) + n));
    // search diagonally-bottom-left-top-right
    let top_to_bottom_left =
        (0..width).map(|col| (0..min(diag, col)).map(move |n| col + n * (width - 1)));
    let right_to_bottom_left = (0..height).map(|row| {
        (0..min(diag, height - row)).map(move |n| {
            let m = n + 1;
            width * (row + m) - m
        })
    });

    // FIXME: this doesn't work, so learn more Rust to DRY
    // let all = horizontal
    //     .chain(vertical)
    //     .chain(top_to_bottom_right)
    //     .chain(left_to_bottom_right)
    //     .chain(top_to_bottom_left)
    //     .chain(right_to_bottom_left);

    let max_h = max_of_lines(grid, n, horizontal);
    // let max_h = horizontal
    //     .map(|line| {
    //         largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n)
    //     })
    //     .max()
    //     .unwrap();

    let max_v = max_of_lines(grid, n, vertical);
    // let max_v = vertical
    //     .map(|line| {
    //         largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n)
    //     })
    //     .max()
    //     .unwrap();

    let max_ttbr = max_of_lines(grid, n, top_to_bottom_right);
    // let max_ttbr = top_to_bottom_right
    //     .map(|line| {
    //         largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n)
    //     })
    //     .max()
    //     .unwrap();

    let max_ltbr = max_of_lines(grid, n, left_to_bottom_right);
    // let max_ltbr = left_to_bottom_right
    //     .map(|line| {
    //         largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n)
    //     })
    //     .max()
    //     .unwrap();

    let max_ttbl = max_of_lines(grid, n, top_to_bottom_left);
    // let max_ttbl = top_to_bottom_left
    //     .map(|line| {
    //         largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n)
    //     })
    //     .max()
    //     .unwrap();

    let max_rtbl = max_of_lines(grid, n, right_to_bottom_left);
    // let max_rtbl = right_to_bottom_left
    //     .map(|line| {
    //         largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n)
    //     })
    //     .max()
    //     .unwrap();

    vec![max_h, max_v, max_ttbr, max_ltbr, max_ttbl, max_rtbl]
        .into_iter()
        .max()
        .unwrap()
    // all.map(|line| largest_adjacent_product_of_length(&line.map(|idx| grid[idx]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), n))
    //     .max()
    //     .unwrap()
}

fn largest_adjacent_product_of_length(nums: &[usize], n: usize) -> usize {
    fn largest_adjacent_product_of_length_no_zeros(nums: &[usize], n: usize) -> usize {
        if nums.len() < n {
            return 0;
        }
        let mut product: usize = nums[0..n].iter().product();
        let mut max_product = product;
        for i in n..nums.len() {
            product = product * nums[i] / nums[i - n];
            max_product = max_product.max(product);
        }
        max_product
    }
    nums.split(|&n| n == 0)
        .map(|s| largest_adjacent_product_of_length_no_zeros(s, n))
        .max()
        .unwrap()
}

pub fn read_grid(grid: &str) -> Vec<usize> {
    grid.split_whitespace()
        .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap_or(0))
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `max_of_lines`

The signature can be made somewhat readable by naming all of the types so that you can refer to them more naturally:

```
fn max_of_lines<A, B, C, D>(grid: &[usize], n: usize, lines: A) -> usize
where
    A: Iterator<Item=B>,
    B: Iterator<Item=C>,
    C: SliceIndex<[usize], Output=D>,
    D: Copy + Sized,
    Vec<usize>: FromIterator<D>,
```

However, you might have fallen victim to over-generalization here. You only ever use the functions with iterators returning `usize`, so you could make the signature even cleaner by making that explicit:

```
fn max_of_lines<A, B>(grid: &[usize], n: usize, lines: A) -> usize
where
    A: Iterator<Item=B>,
    B: Iterator<Item=usize>,
```

#### `chain`

As you noted in your question, the real way to improve the code is to make use of `chain`. The reason you cannot use it currently is because the signature requires both iterators to return items of the same type, while each one of your returns a different type as *every closure has a unique type*.
You could solve this by `Box`ing the inner iterators to create [trait objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567849/what-makes-something-a-trait-object).
However, eventually you end up converting the inner iterator to `Vec<usize>` anyway, so it makes sense to do it immediately, e.g. with `vertical`:

```
let vertical = (0..width).map(|col| {
    (0..height)
        .map(move |n| grid[col + n * width])
        .collect::<Vec<usize>>()
});
```

Converting the rest similarly, you will be able to use your initial idea with `chain` and get rid of the `max_of_lines` function completely.

#### Error handling

While for Project Euler handling errors robustly is not necessary, I would stress that you shouldn't silently ignore errors as that can easily introduce subtle bugs.

In particular, in `read_grid`,

```
.map(|s| s.parse().unwrap_or(0))
```

will silently ignore any parsing error and pretend it found 0.
You should use the following instead which will explicitly throw an error

```
.map(|s| s.parse().expect("couldn't parse grid element"))
```

#### `largest_adjacent_product_of_length`

Your implementation of this function can be improved to only need a single pass through the array, instead of one for `split` and another one for the actual calculation.

```
let (mut product, mut max) = (1, 0);
let mut len = 0;
for i in 0..nums.len() {
    if nums[i] == 0 {
        product = 1;
        len = 0;
    } else {
        product *= nums[i];
        if len < n {
            len += 1;
        } else {
            product /= nums[i - len];
        }
        max = max.max(product);
    }
}
max
```

Alternatively, if `n` is small, you could go for a slower but more readable approach.

```
nums.windows(n)
    .map(|arr| arr.iter().product())
    .max()
    .unwrap_or(0)
```

#### Final code [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b588646557d49cb9c08d472330daf49b)

#### Grid representation

You chose to represent the grid as a one-dimensional array. While this is potentially better for performance, it makes the code more difficult to read and reason about so I would suggest using `Vec<Vec<usize>>` instead; I'll leave that as an exercise to you :)